# Java bounce physics : never ending bounce

Tags: java, physics, infinite, bounce

I have recently started programming games in java. I come from a C# / XNA background and i already have experience in game development.
However I have a problem in my java game. I have a bouncing script which makes a in-game "particle" bounce upon collision with a solid surface, such as the ground.
Here is a snippet of the code that manages the bouncing.

```
private final void respondY(Rectangle r)
{
    if(!r.intersects(getBounds())) // If not colliding, return
        return;

    if(Yvel > 0) // If falling...
    {
        if(r.y < Y + Height) //Another collision test
        {
            Y = r.y - Height; // Set Y to top of object
            Yvel *= -bounce; // Bounce (Here is the problem)
            onFloor = true;
        }
    }
    else if(Yvel < 0) // If hit ceiling
    {
        if(Y < r.y + r.height) // Collision test
        {
            Y = r.y + r.height; // Set Y to bottom of object
            Yvel = 0; // No bouncing here
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem is that the object bounces upon the floor as it should, but after a while the object bounces constantly at the same height where I want it to stop bouncing when it got to that constant height.**

NOTE:

- Yvel is a int that is the vertical velocity of the object
- Bounce is a float that controls how "bouncy" a object is. e.g. 0.5 means that it bounces half as high as it fell

Thanks in advance! Please note that this is my first post so if I make mistakes please point them out in a constructive manner.

Answer (score 1):

The `float` (and `double`) types are imprecise. This especially causes problems when dealing with very small numbers - in fact there's a smallest representable number and a finite quantity of possible numbers that can be represented (and bit like quantum physics). The number stored by a `float` is actually the closest number possible to represent to the calculation result.

What's happening is the velocity calculation never reaches zero, because the result of multiplying the smallest number `float` can represent by a value >= .5 is itself.

I would force it to zero by putting a low threshold on the calculation result:

```
Yvel = Yvel * -bounce;
if (Yvel < .000001F)
    Yvel = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but when I tried this but the problem persists.  The 'if(Yvel < 0)' line stops the object from bouncing at all, and if removed the objects still bounce at the same height. Changing .0001f to something larger like .01f makes the constant bounce height smaller, but it still is there... Maybe something could be done with Math.round()...

Comment: EDIT : I had not seen your edit in your answer when I was writing the last comment, I am currently trying to detect if a object repeatedly bounces to the same height and if so stop the object when it hits the ground.